# Why do the threads in my activity perform in a synchronized way when I close and start an activity?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, androidhttpclient

My scenario is like the following:
I have an activity A, 
in which I start an `AsyncTask` with thread t1 with `HttpGet` request with a 3s timeout, 
after t1 times out, I start t2 with `HttpGet` request with a 30s timeout.

Now I start activity A, and I intentionally throw the `HttpPost` request with my proxy fiddler,  after t1 times out but t2 is running, I stop and restart the activity quickly.
A strange thing happens, the new t1 waits until the old t2 times out.

Can anyone explain why this kind of thing happens in Android, why t1 doesn't start immediately after I restart activity A, how to make t1 start immediately after the activity restarts?

My test code is

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        httpget("http://www.baidu.com",3000);
        httpget("http://www.baidu.com",30000);
        return "test";
    }

    protected void onCancelled() {
        super.onCancelled();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    new MyAsyncTask().execute("start");
}
```

The log result is shown below, the second "httpget start timeout is 3000" appears after t2 
finished even though I restart the activity quite quickly.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of 3.0, AsyncTasks all run round robin on a single thread, because Google thought app developers were too stupid to write concurrent code.  Actually, the questions on this site make me think they're probably right.  You can override that behavior by using AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor() instead of execute when starting the task.